# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pool has been closed

Tags: java, google-cloud-spanner

Getting the below exception for both read and write operations to google spanner through a REST API

Have created spanner instance and data base and tables manually and trying to read and write to spanner tables , getting this error. Wanted to know if this error comes due to configuration or the by the code at runtime.

Help me troubleshoot this issue

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pool has been closed
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SessionPool.getReadSession(SessionPool.java:834) ~[google-cloud-spanner-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0]
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.DatabaseClientImpl.singleUse(DatabaseClientImpl.java:72) ~[google-cloud-spanner-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0]

Answer (score 0):

This error is originating from the Spanner client library, and not the REST API. It is an indication that you have closed the `Spanner` instance that you used to get a `DatabaseClient`, while you are still using the `DatabaseClient`. So the following example would force-trigger this error:

```java
    Spanner spanner = SpannerOptions.newBuilder()
        .setProjectId("project-id")
        .build()
        .getService();
    DatabaseClient client = spanner.getDatabaseClient(DatabaseId.of("project-id", "instance-id", "database-id"));

    // Don't to this if you intend to use the DatabaseClient you just got on
    // the previous line at a later moment.
    spanner.close();

    // The following line will trigger the error mentioned.
    try(ResultSet rs = client.singleUse().executeQuery(Statement.of("SELECT * FROM FOO"))) {
      while(rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getCurrentRowAsStruct().toString());
      }
    }
```

`Spanner` instances should normally live throughout the entire lifetime of your application. You should only close it if you are sure that you will no longer have any further interaction with the database.